# Website not zoomed in properly in Iphone

Tags: iphone, css, layout

I'm scratching my head on this one and hoping someone can help me out.
The site is: http://highlandsharvest.com

On Iphones, you see the narrow dark column on the right hand side. I want to get rid of this.

I played around with the "viewport" meta, changing the width to the width of the website itself, but no good - no changes.

The viewport meta is currently set to:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 960">
```

What else should I try to get Iphone to zoom in properly on the site?

Thanks so much beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

The width isn't 960, height is. Also, try Scale to fit on the properties